# Not able to query on standard Asset field 'ProductCode' . Please suggest

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

```
List<Asset> lst= [select Id, ProductCode, Product_Family1__c, Product_Family__c from Asset WHERE AccountId = '0015000000IBGof' AND (
                            (NOT IB_Status__c Like  '%eval%') OR
                            (NOT IB_Status__c Like  '%Under Right of Return%') OR
                            (NOT IB_Status__c Like  '%Sold - Demo%') OR
                            (NOT IB_Status__c Like  '%WRITTEN OFF%')
                        ) 
                         AND Product_Family__c != 'Whitewater'];
```

I am getting below error
No such column 'ProductCode' on entity 'Asset'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Also I need to use group by (Product_Family1__c, Product_Family__c) this query But getting error

Comment: `ProductCode` is not a field on `Asset` - see doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_asset.htm?search_text=asset; @Torsen has solution

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Visibily on that Field? Default standard Product Code in asset object is not visible, otherwise you can access to the ProductCode by Product2.ProductCode.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want the Product Code field or if you just need the record Id.

The field on the Asset object is 'Product2Id', and if you need the Product Code, you can query for 'Product2.ProductCode'.

A good way to test a query is to go to the Developer Console and open the object under the File menu. From there you can see the fields/types and test queries.